# PySpark - Return first row from each file in a folder

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have multiple .csv files in a folder on Azure. Using PySpark I am trying to create a dataframe that has two columns, filename and firstrow, which are captured for each file within the folder.

Ideally I would like to avoid having to read the files in full as some of them can be quite large.

I am new to PySpark so I do not yet understand the basics so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Would you mind to share more about why do you need to achieve your task by using PySpark? I believe it will be much faster by using `open()` and `.readline()` built-in python function

Comment: Not at all.  I am currently working with a team to build an analytical solution in Azure Synapse.  We have 100s of large files that need to be put through an ELT process.  Files are grouped into different file formats so the first step is to identify the file format.  The most efficient way to do this is to read the first row and match it against a regex pattern.  Once this is done then the file can be transformed and loaded into the model.

I am using PySpark because this is what is available in Azure Synapse, this process was too complex for pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have write a code for your scenario and it is working fine.

1. Create a empty list and append it with all the filenames stored in the source

```
# read filenames
filenames = []
l = dbutils.fs.ls("/FileStore/tables/")
for i in l:
    print(i.name)
    filenames.append(i.name)
# converting filenames to tuple
d = [(x,) for x in filenames]
print(d)
```

[image]

2. Read the data from multiple files and store in a list

```
# create data by reading from multiple files
data = []
i = 0
for n in filename:
    temp = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/FileStore/tables/" + n).limit(1)
    temp = temp.collect()[0]
    temp = str(temp)
    s = d[i] + (temp,)
    data.append(s)
    i+=1
print(data)
```

[image]

3. Now create DataFrame from the data with column names.

```
column = ["filename", "filedata"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, column)
df.head(2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a very thorough response, I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: yes, please try it and let me know.

Comment: I have an error with cell 1:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.dbutils'
I am using Azure Synapse PySpark, not Databricks, I wondered if that will cause this to error?

Comment: So I have the first cell working by using mssparkutils instead of dbutils.

Comment: there might be some libraries dependencies, you need to check on that.

Comment: I have this working and it does what I asked for so many thanks for your help!